# Sencha touch 2. Text doesn't obey the flex parameter in list item

Tags: list, listview, extjs, plugins, sencha-touch-2

I have defined this `Ext.dataview.component.ListItem` which renders some data from store into a list, but I cannot make the first text item to obey the flex rule and it's really annoying. It doesn't obey absolute width either. I have read all the documentation, but cannot figure this out by my self.

```
Ext.define('MyProgram.view.DataItem', {
extend : 'Ext.dataview.component.ListItem',
xtype  : 'basic-dataitem',

requires : [
    'Ext.Button',
    'Ext.Component',
    'Ext.layout.HBox',
    'Ext.field.Checkbox'
],
config : {
    text : {
        flex : 1//This text doesn't take one out of two space in my list item
    },
    moreText : {
        flex : 1//This text takes one out of one space???
    },

    dataMap :{
        getText : {
            setHtml : 'text'
        },
        getMoreText : {
            setHtml : 'moreText'
        }
    },

    layout : {
        //I want texts to obey hbox layout
        type : 'hbox',
        align: 'center'
    }
}
});
```

And here is the code for my `Ext.dataview.List` which uses the previously introduced list item `MyProgram.view.DataItem`:

```
 Ext.define('MyProgram.view.Main', {
extend : 'Ext.dataview.List',
xtype  : 'main',
id: 'MainList',
requires : [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'Ext.data.Store',
    'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
    'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
    'MyProgram.view.DataItem'
],

config : {
    store : 'TodoItems',
    useSimpleItems : false,
    defaultType    : 'basic-dataitem',

    plugins : [
        {
            xclass          : 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
            pullText : 'Pull down to refresh!'//Valid
            //pullRefreshText : 'Pull down to refresh!'//Deprecated
        },
        {
            xclass     : 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging : true
        }
    ],

    scrollable : {
        direction     : 'vertical',
        directionLock : true
    },

    items : [
        {
            docked : 'top',
            xtype  : 'titlebar',
            title  : 'List using list items'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I want to disable the default `itemTpl`, so I can prevent sencha from adding raw `htlm` before my containers. I set my `itemTpl` in my list view to `''` so it won't use the default `'{text}'` template for my model which ruins my styling.